# Properties of added attributes in DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider don't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm trying to replace several dataannotation attributes with one custom by using the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider

So I created a fake attribute:

```
public class TestAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
}
```

And decorate my model properties with this attribute.

and use the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider to add several other attributes based on if TestAttribute is set:

```
    public class MyCustomMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var attributeList = attributes.ToList();
        if (attributeList.OfType<TestAttribute>().Any())
        {
            var req = new RequiredAttribute();
            attributeList.Add(req);
        }

        return base.CreateMetadata(attributeList, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
    }
}
```

This works. Properties with the test attribute are now required.

What does not work is setting properties on the RequiredAttribute object.. like so:

```
        var attributeList = attributes.ToList();
        if (attributeList.OfType<CurrencyAttribute>().Any())
        {
            var req = new RequiredAttribute();
            req.ErrorMessage = "Test test";
            attributeList.Add(req);
        }
```

The error message will still be: "The xx field is required."

Why is that?